# How do I hide the + sign from the WinForms ReportViewer?

Tags: reportviewer

I'm a bit new to reportviewer so I have a question that could solve my doubts about it. I created a DataSet and bind the table using the DataSet and created a report and show the data using the reportviewer. Here comes the problem that I can't seems to solve it. Below were the pictures that I am showing to you guys.

[image]

Notice the + sign in the box? How to make the reportviewer that it wouldn't show the + sign and immediately shows every data that I put. I need to click several times in order to see the entire data inside the reportviewer like the picture below.

[image]

Comment: http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Web_0_0x2e_1.aspx

Comment: Excuse me, but I doubt the link is the solution to my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the answer to that doubts. It is to unselect the 'Expand/collapse' groups check box when you were creating.